# Get Object name as string MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop

I want to find a way to get the name of an instance of an object in MATLAB and return it within itself in MATLAB R2019b.

So in the Launcher Constructor define the instances like this

```
Properties
    TorqueViewComponent
    SpeedViewComponent
end

methods
    function obj = Launcher()
        TorqueViewComponent = GraphView(args...);
        SpeedViewComponent = GraphView(args...);
    end
end
```

and then within the graph view object constructor something like

```
function obj = GraphView(args...)
    if strcmp(object name, 'TorqueViewComponent')
        do some things;
    elseif strcmp(object name, 'SpeedViewComponent')
        do some other things;
    end
end
```

In essence I have multiple instances of the GraphView object, which I want to plot different sets of data based on the name of the instance.

If you have any questions let me know and I can go over the problem in a little more detail

Comment: Even if there is, this is very bad design. You are much better off passing the name as an argument. Not to mention, if you really want your GraphView class to do two different things, then really it should be two different classes (which you can wrap in a 'dispatcher' class if you want a single interface). Have a look at the [SOLID principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)

Comment: The 'do some things' and 'do some other things' part may have been a bit misleading, doing different things just means what ylabel, title and y axis data is being plotted, the graphs that are being created are identical aside from that. so for instance do some things would be ylabel(obj.Axes, 'Torque [Nm]'); title('Torque'); and then do some other things would be ylabel(obj.Axes, 'Speed [rpm]'); title('Speed');.

Answer (score 2):

You really only have two options; either subclass Graphview to create specialised subclasses, or pass an extra input argument. There *might* be some hacky solution to allow you to somehow get the name from the caller workspace, but this is highly unlikely to improve readability and maintainability of your code.

#### Subclassing

E.g.

```
classdef TorqueGraphView < GraphView
   methods
      function obj = TorqueGraphView(varargin)
         obj@SuperClass(varargin);
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

In fact, if you don't really need to pass extra arguments to TorqueGraphView, you can take advantage of the fact that you can make an [Implicit Call to Inherited Constructor](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html#brustg9)

```
classdef TorqueGraphView < GraphView
    % ... no constructor, only Torque-specific methods here
end
```

#### Explicit input arguments

Otherwise, if you think this is overkill for such small adjustments, you really have to pass an argument to indicate this. If your main concern is 'messiness', you can consider packaging your arguments into a struct, which looks a bit more tidy. This might even help you nicely separate object-specific arguments from generic / option related arguments, e.g.

```
TorqueArgs = struct(                  ...
    'type'        ,   'torque'      , ...
    'initialvalue',   0             , ...
    'ylabel'      ,   'Torque [Nm]' , ...
    'plottitle'   ,   'Torque'        )

GraphOpts = struct (      ...
    'axescolor',   'k'  , ...
    'linewidth',   3,   , ...
    'grid'     ,   'on'   )

TorqueViewComponent = GraphView( TorqueArgs, GraphOpts );
```

Comment: Thanks Tasos, I have fixed the issue by just passing one additional argument to the GraphView class that is just a string of either 'Torque' or 'Speed' and then the GraphView class plots the correct data based on what that argument is. A struct could work there but i'm hesitant to do that just to keep the top level launcher tidy, i think really the cleaner fix is to rework some of the other areas of the application but thats a bit beyond the scope of my original question

Answer (score 0):

You added in the comments that this was to influence things like the `ylabel` of the plot.

You could use `inputname` to get around this, but you'd have to split the function out, as the variable needs to be defined first.

```
function ylabelVarName( v )
    ylabel( inputname(1) )
end
```

Then

```
function obj = Launcher()
    TorqueViewComponent = GraphView(args...);
    ylabelVarName( TorqueViewComponent );
    SpeedViewComponent = GraphView(args...); 
    ylabelVarName( SpeedViewComponent );
end
```

You could probably make this part of the `GraphView` class, but I can't see how you'd get around doing it in two lines.

---

Really though, I think the correct answer is to just use an additional input argument for your `GraphView` function which specifies your preferences in terms of axis labels etc.

Comment: Yeah I started out trying to do it with arguments but found it messy with the amount of arguments i would have needed to pass to the object, that said i might be able to get around it by just passing a "type" argument and then if that is satisfied to say "speed" then GraphView sets the title and ylabel internally